# Plugged power but pending-charge anyway ASUS ROG 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: asus, battery, charging

I alwais have a not charging icon in the top bar. This is the output of upower -d when laptop is plugged in:

```
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC0
  native-path:          AC0
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              mar 16 nov 2021 20:44:16 (90 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    warning-level:       none
    online:              yes
    icon-name:          'ac-adapter-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               ASUSTeK
  model:                ASUS Battery
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              mar 16 nov 2021 20:44:16 (90 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               pending-charge
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              57,252 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         58,741 Wh
    energy-full-design:  66 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    voltage:             15,677 V
    percentage:          97%
    capacity:            89,0015%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charging-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1637091856  0,000   unknown
  History (rate):
    1637091856  0,000   unknown

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              mar 16 nov 2021 20:44:16 (90 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  battery
    present:             yes
    state:               pending-charge
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              57,252 Wh
    energy-full:         58,741 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    percentage:          97%
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charging-symbolic'

Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.99.11
  on-battery:      no
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  yes
  critical-action: HybridSleep
```

Meanwhile the laptop seems is not discharging, always on 97%

Comment: If you mention it doesn't discharge (not displayed as doing so) :  1st case your batteries are bad/old and doesn't charge/discharge enough for software detection  but are still OK on electric way. 2cd case it is only a GUI issue, 3rd like first case batteries are no more ok, but are detected when plugged, & act just like a super-capacitor or a very short secure  power.  Finally, no, a battery will never really be 100%  because BMS (electronic battery management system) make it charge/discharge cycles permanently to avoid batteries to get too old too fast for their health.

Comment: I've other OS on the laptop and are working perfect and the laptop is 6 months old. The problem is that Im unable to manage the power profiles when charging/not charging

Comment: ok then it is the 2cd case, GUI issue only.

Comment: So, please, edit the question and post the Ubuntu release/version.

Comment: Bum up! edited with ubuntu version, does somebody has any clue?

Answer (score 2):

The pending-charge state means AC power is on but the battery is not
being charged. This can happen because its charge is above a certain
threshold, to avoid short charging cycles and prolong the battery's
life, or because the PSU is not powerful enough to charge the batteries.

Answer (score 0):

if you are here because you are afraid of "my charger is not working!" and your battery level is "low", then relax, just give it few minuets and it shows "charging". Let's leave technical discussion behind ... :-D